# What's wrong with this method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm getting a warning: "Return makes pointer from integer without a cast" for this method...

```
+(BOOL *)getBoolFromString:(NSString *)boolStr  
{  
    if(boolStr == @"true" || boolStr == @"1"){  
        return YES;  
    }  
    return NO;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BOOL is not a class or object, so returning a pointer to a BOOL is not the same as returning a BOOL.

You should remove the * in `+(BOOL *)` and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 8):

Besides what @Jasarien and @jlehr have said, you have a problem with this:

```
(boolStr == @"true" || boolStr == @"1")
```

That's doing pointer comparison, not object equality.  You want:

```
([boolStr isEqualToString:@"true"] || [boolStr isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

Answer (score 6):

To get a BOOL from an NSString, all you need to do is send a `-boolValue` message, like so:

```
NSString *myString = @"true"; // or @"YES", etc.
BOOL bool = [myString boolValue];
```

Comment: To be specific, from the docementation: `Returns YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9—the method ignores any trailing characters.`